# Box Java SDK throws NullPointerException when trying to refresh a revoked token

Tags: box-api

We're using the latest version of the Box Java SDK to finish our port from the Box v1 API to the Box v2 API. Overall the SDK is great, and a huge time-saver over what we had to do with V1.

However, I've encountered a problem in testing that I believe should be fixed. If you try to call the BoxOAuthManager.refreshOAuth method using a token that has been revoked on the Box side, the method throws a NullPointerException.  Here's a code sample (assumes you have valid values for token/credentials, and a BoxClient instance in CLIENT):

```
BoxOAuthRequestObject refreshRequest = 
    BoxOAuthRequestObject.refreshOAuthRequestObject(REFRESH_TOKEN, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

BoxOAuthToken boxToken = CLIENT.getOAuthManager().refreshOAuth(refreshRequest);
```

I would expect this to throw an AuthFatalFailureException if the refresh token is invalid, but instead it throws a NullPointerException. So as a workaround we are making sure to catch the NullPointerException in our code and respond appropriately.

The null pointer appears to be on line 36 of ErrorResponseParser.java.

Comment: Thanks -- I have copied your post into the GitHub repo for the Java SDK: see [this issue](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/issues/47) if you have additional comments or want to track progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the line number, I think the version you're using is before v2.0.4, 2.0.4 actually fixed this issue. Can you try the latest version 2.0.6?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at the latest code, what I had was a couple weeks old. However, with the latest code I still get a NullPointerException, just in a different place. See the issue in the GitHub repo for details.

Comment: It should be a BoxServerException. This exception is thrown whenever you don't get expected api response. It contains detailed information of what's going wrong.